# Make rearranging rules?

Tags: makefile

I have a `Makefile` which compiles C code on Ubuntu Linux 13.04. It looks something like this:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=-lm
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECS=$(SOURCES:%.c=%)

all: $(OBJECTS) $(EXECS)
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
.o.:
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Now, `ld` wants `$(LDFLAGS)` to appear at the end of the line where I have put it above. When I run `make` on this `Makefile` I get the following sort of output:

```
$ make
gcc -c -Wall FILENAME.c -o FILENAME.o
...
gcc -lm  FILENAME.o   -o FILENAME
...
```

Why does the `-lm` appear after the C compiler on the second line and not at the end of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this rule:

```
.o.:
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

has no effect.  You're telling make how to build the literal file named `.o.` but since you don't try to build that file, this rule is ignored.  You should use simply `.o` (no other period) if you're trying to specify a single-suffix rule.

Because your makefile doesn't define a rule to build `FILENAME`, make is searching its built-in library of implicit rules to find one to build the executable.  In the standard built-in library of rules, the `LDFLAGS` variable is for linker flags like `-L` etc. which specify pathnames and should come before all the libraries.  The variable `LDLIBS` is for specifying libraries to link, such as `-lm`.

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend using suffix rules.  You're already committed to using GNU make by using `$(wildcard ...)` etc. so you might as well use pattern rules.  They're much simpler to read and understand.  Or, don't bother writing any rules and use make's built-in rules!  That's even better, unless you have some requirement they can't satisfy.

Comment: And PPS, you can see make's built-in library of rules and variables by running `make -p -f /dev/null`.

Comment: Hmm. My understanding was that the `all` rule requires `$(OBJECTS)` to be built as a prerequisite to `$(EXECS)`. Why is that not the case?

Comment: Why do you think that's not the case?  It built the objects, right?

Comment: Yes, it's building the objects, but your answer says that the rule above has no effect. So... it is building the objects, but the rule for building objects is not being used?

Comment: Yes, but the `.o.` rule is for building the executable.  That has no effect.  The `.o.c` rule is for building the objects.  That one works.  The syntax for "build a file with no extension from a file with a .o extension is `.o`, not `.o.`.  In any event, as I mentioned, GNU make has lots of built-in rules so even if none of the rules in your makefile had any effect, make would still know how to compile and link.

Comment: In my case that default rule does not work with my version of `ld`, so really I need to fix the Makefile.

Comment: You do need to fix your makefile.  However, the default rules will work _if_, as I mentioned in my answer, you use the right variable.  `LDFLAGS` is not for libraries, it's for `-L`, etc.  Put the libraries like `-lm` in the `LDLIBS` variable, not `LDFLAGS`, then it will work.

Comment: Argh, sorry you are quite right. LDLIBS does work, so long as I remove all the rubbish that doesn't work first!